# Type of Shading Maps

Tags: texturing, materials, image

I am texturing maps in blender and am using some models ripped from games. I came across some maps that are Black, Green, and Red. I don't know what they are used for e.g.roughness, metallic, normals, etc. All I know is it is named "W". Normally AO is Ambient Occlusion, CS or Diffuse for base color etc., but I can't understand what "W" would stand for.
[image: T_D_Assault_NewEra_01_Helmet_W]

Comment: Game textures usually use a technique called Channel Packing.  If you use a separate rgb node it's likely that each color is a different map.

Comment: Yes, since a roughness, ambient occlusion and metalness map are all black and white, it saves memory to put all three of those into one texture. Sometimes a studio might but a Height map into the alpha channel as well.

Answer (score 2):

It definitely looks like a channel pack. Now the issue is, there isn't really a standard as to what kind of data is stored and in which order, anyone does pretty much whatever they want, and it's usually a bunch of rules set on a per-production basis for consistency, or it's hard coded in the softwares made to produce these channel packs.
That being said, one common packing is "RMA": Roughness, Metallic, Ambient occlusion. Though, again, while people might indeed pack these three data, they might not do it in that particular order. Especially when for example they have no metallic parts on a model: they often will just have another map instead.

So, the first thing you could try to look up to is any kind of documentation from the game. If it has a strong modding community, chances are: modders already figured it out or have at least wild guesses as to how things are usually structured.

A good example of this kind of "community studies" could be [Technical Study: Overwatch [Image heavy] — polycount](https://polycount.com/discussion/170394/technical-study-overwatch-image-heavy).
Which, by the way, I really encourage anyone doing 3D to read through. It's simply interesting, and it showcases well executed examples of how to obtain HQ-looking stuff at a low resource impact. And these are techniques anyone can use anywhere, not just video games, and for great benefits.

Now, trying to find the answer someone else already found for your specific case is usually the safest, but if you are experienced with textures, it might be faster to just load up the texture in an editing software like GIMP or Krita and look at the channels individually by yourself. Some textures are somewhat easy to differentiate, especially if you know how the original model reacts to light.